Border for expansion panel items in Flutter
I am trying to add borders for each item in an expansion panel in Flutter.
I achieved the below by the code below.
The problem is that the border lines doesn't cover entire width, but only till the up/down arrow.
I want the border to be full.
Can anyone please help me?

                        ExpansionPanel(
                          canTapOnHeader: true,
                          headerBuilder:
                              (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                            return Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical:
                                      4.0), // Add vertical margin to separate panels
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                                  top: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.grey, // Border color
                                    width: 1.0, // Border width
                                  ),
                                  bottom: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.transparent, // Border color
                                    width: 1.0, // Border width
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                'Which city do you want to travel from?',
                                style: Theme.of(context)
                                    .textTheme
                                    .titleSmall!
                                    .copyWith(
                                      height: 1.5,
                                      color: const Color(0xFF171A1F),
                                    ),
                              )),
                            );
                          },
                          .....//the body code 

This is the output when I used default elevation (Which added shadow and left and right borders etc, which I am not expecting):


                    ExpansionPanelList(
                      elevation: 4,
                      expandedHeaderPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      materialGapSize: 1,
                      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
                        setState(() {
                          _openIndex = isExpanded ? index : -1;
                        });
                      },
                      children: [
                        ExpansionPanel(
                          canTapOnHeader: true,
                          headerBuilder:
                              (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                'Which city do you want to take the higher education in?',
                                style: Theme.of(context)
                                    .textTheme
                                    .titleSmall!
                                    .copyWith(
                                      height: 1.5,
                                      color: const Color(0xFF171A1F),
                                    ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          body: ...


I think you don't need that container to do that separation between those Panels, you can just wrap all of the ExpansionPanels you have with an ExpansionPanelList which give some sort of elevation for each one which leads to be separated:

  ExpansionPanelList(
    children: [
      ExpansionPanel(
        body: Text('Hi....is it a body 1 ?'),
        headerBuilder: (context,expanded){
          return Text('Expansion panel 1');
        },
      ),
      ExpansionPanel(
        body: Text('Hi....is it a body 2 ?'),
        headerBuilder: (context,expanded){
          return Text('Expansion panel 2');
        },
      ),
      ExpansionPanel(
        body: Text('Hi....is it a body 3 ?'),
        headerBuilder: (context,expanded){
          return Text('Expansion panel 3');
        },
      )
    ],
  )


I tried that.
Attached a new image when I used elevation in the question.
It give me shadow and left and right borders etc.

@Harikrishnan, i think it's has no problem but you should have a small elevation like 1 or 0.75 and don't make a horizontal padding for the expansion panel list, if it's inside another widget that uses a padding in the whole screen, remove that padding.
